# JQuery not executing on Document Ready

Tags: jquery

```
if ($("#IndicationCalculatorGroupId option:selected").text() == 'Create a New Group')
                {
                    $("#newGroupNameRow").show();
                }

            $("#IndicationCalculatorGroupId").change(function() {
                if ($("#IndicationCalculatorGroupId option:selected").text() == 'Create a New Group')
                {
                    $("#newGroupNameRow").show();
                }
                else{
                    $("#IndicationCalculatorNewGroupName").val('');
                    $("#newGroupNameRow").hide();
                }
            });
```

I have that in my document ready. Basically when the page loads, I want to check to see if the one dropdown has a certain value, and if it does, show a certain div. The onChange() events work correctly, so I know that check is done properly, it just doesn't seem to work onDocumentReady. The div won't show().

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may miss :

To set the default selected value of "IndicationCalculatorGroupId" and you need to call

```
$("#IndicationCalculatorGroupId").change()
```

after your change function to execute your login in change event.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code here http://jsfiddle.net/DkZpB/ and it seems to work ok. The one thing I did notice was that when I used an inline style on `<div id="newGroupNameRow">`, the `.show()` method didn't do anything.  I had to set `display:none` via CSS instead, or call `.hide()` as the first thing on `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Ya, I just meant that if he wants the initial state to be hidden it needs to be done via CSS or `.hide()`, rather than inline styles.